# IE 9+ Rendering Spaces Differently

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

An authoring tool I'm required to use decided to output faux bullet points rather than using bullet elements. The poor decision causes IE 9+ to render different than IE 7/8 and all other browsers. I can't change the way it outputs, but I can influence it with additional style properties. To do that I need help to identify what exactly is causing the difference. If you can put aside the horror you're about to witness, I would appreciate any advice. It might have something to do with the multiple non-breaking space characters; as if IE 9+ is deleting all but the first.

Here is the sample page: http://www.scader.com/clients/sandbox/bullets

Here is a jsFiddle that displays the issue if you view in IE 9+: http://jsfiddle.net/QGV7W/1/

Here is a screen shot that shows the difference between IE 7/8 (+all others) and IE 9+.

[image]

Here is a snippit of the code:

```
<p style="margin-left:24px;text-indent:-24px;line-height:1.080;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;text-align:left;">
<span class="text38Font2" style="position:relative;top:-0px">2.</span><span style="font:1.0pt &quot;Arial&quot;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="text38Font2">literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. 
Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-
Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more 
obscure Latin words, consectetur,
</span></p>
```

Here is the one class referenced in the snippet:

```
<style text="text/css">
  body { background-color:#ffffff; }
  span.text38Font2 { font-size:16px; font-family:"Arial", sans-serif; color:#000000;}
</style>
```

Comment: you don't have a stylesheet for fix ie bugs ?

Comment: By default, no. I might be able to add them. First I'm trying to identify the problem.

Comment: `style="top:-0px"`, You should remove this. Change it to `style="top:0px"`

Comment: i believe you don't need to test IE7 anymore. But it looks good on both IE 7/8

Comment: Your problem is `<span style="font:1.0pt &quot;Arial&quot;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>` this part

Comment: @ViliusL IE7/8 look fine, it's IE 9+ that has the issue.

Comment: not only IE9+, chrome 31 also has a indent problem. if you can't control the output you may have to override this with css hack, would be a pain though. the cause of this problem, is that you have multiple non-break stops '&nbsp;' after each number, and different browsers has a different default width for that

Comment: @Ani I changed the style to remove the minus, but didn't help. I agree the &nbsp; could likely be the concern, but why does it render differently?

Comment: Also, Why are you adding `&quot;Arial&quot;` You can just write `style="font:1.0pt Arial">`

Comment: @Godinall My primary browser is Chrome (v31) and it seems to render correctly. I'm a little surprised that a space character, with the font specifically set, would render differently, particularly to that extreme.

Comment: @Ani It's not me--it's the authoring tool that generated all the output except for the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you can do:

**CSS**

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
    .space{
        font:2.0pt !important;
    }
<!--[endif]-->
```

**HTML**

```
<span style="font:1.0pt &quot;Arial&quot;" class="space">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
```

Comment: I won't be able to easily tag it with the special class, but this does resolve the issue, so I'll figure out how to apply this fix through another selector method.